# How to generate code from flow chart graph in javascript

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js, vuejs2, flowchart

am using [baklavajs](https://github.com/newcat/baklavajs) library to create flow chart, i have some custom nodes like SwitchNode, SayTextNode..

For example i have the following flow chart:

[image]

And i need to generate the code below:

```
print("hi")
print("How i can help")

input = input()
if input == 1:
    print("one")

if input == 2:
    print("two")

if input == 3:
    print("three")
```

Also the library generate json object contain all nodes and the connection of each node, for this example the generated json object :

```
{
  "nodes": [
    {
      "type": "StartNode",
      "id": "node_16655291011630",
      "name": "Start",
      "options": [
        [
          "Start Text",
          "Hi"
        ]
      ],
      "state": {},
      "interfaces": [
        [
          "Next",
          {
            "id": "ni_16655291011631",
            "value": null
          }
        ]
      ],
      "position": {},
      "width": 200,
      "twoColumn": false,
      "customClasses": ""
    },
    {
      "type": "SayTextNode",
      "id": "node_16655291011642",
      "name": "SayText",
      "options": [
        [
          "Text",
          "How i can help"
        ]
      ],
      "state": {},
      "interfaces": [
        [
          "input",
          {
            "id": "ni_16655291011643",
            "value": null
          }
        ],
        [
          "Next",
          {
            "id": "ni_16655291011654",
            "value": null
          }
        ]
      ],
      "position": {},
      "width": 200,
      "twoColumn": false,
      "customClasses": ""
    },
    {
      "type": "SwitchNode",
      "id": "node_16655291011655",
      "name": "SwitchNode",
      "options": [
        [
          "Operation",
          "Equals"
        ],
        [
          "Cases number",
          3
        ],
        [
          "Case 1",
          "1"
        ],
        [
          "Case 2",
          "2"
        ],
        [
          "Case 3",
          "3"
        ]
      ],
      "state": {},
      "interfaces": [
        [
          "input",
          {
            "id": "ni_16655291011656",
            "value": null
          }
        ],
        [
          "Case 1",
          {
            "id": "ni_166552910116817",
            "value": null
          }
        ],
        [
          "Case 2",
          {
            "id": "ni_166552910116818",
            "value": null
          }
        ],
        [
          "Case 3",
          {
            "id": "ni_166552910116819",
            "value": null
          }
        ]
      ],
      "position": {},
      "width": 200,
      "twoColumn": false,
      "customClasses": ""
    },
    {
      "type": "SayTextNode",
      "id": "node_16655291011668",
      "name": "SayText",
      "options": [
        [
          "Text",
          "one"
        ]
      ],
      "state": {},
      "interfaces": [
        [
          "input",
          {
            "id": "ni_16655291011669",
            "value": null
          }
        ],
        [
          "Next",
          {
            "id": "ni_166552910116610",
            "value": null
          }
        ]
      ],
      "position": {},
      "width": 200,
      "twoColumn": false,
      "customClasses": ""
    },
    {
      "type": "SayTextNode",
      "id": "node_166552910116711",
      "name": "SayText",
      "options": [
        [
          "Text",
          "two"
        ]
      ],
      "state": {},
      "interfaces": [
        [
          "input",
          {
            "id": "ni_166552910116712",
            "value": null
          }
        ],
        [
          "Next",
          {
            "id": "ni_166552910116713",
            "value": null
          }
        ]
      ],
      "position": {},
      "width": 200,
      "twoColumn": false,
      "customClasses": ""
    },
    {
      "type": "SayTextNode",
      "id": "node_166552910116714",
      "name": "SayText",
      "options": [
        [
          "Text",
          "three"
        ]
      ],
      "state": {},
      "interfaces": [
        [
          "input",
          {
            "id": "ni_166552910116715",
            "value": null
          }
        ],
        [
          "Next",
          {
            "id": "ni_166552910116716",
            "value": null
          }
        ]
      ],
      "position": {},
      "width": 200,
      "twoColumn": false,
      "customClasses": ""
    }
  ],
  "connections": [
    {
      "id": "166552910116921",
      "from": "ni_16655291011631",
      "to": "ni_16655291011643"
    },
    {
      "id": "166552910117023",
      "from": "ni_16655291011654",
      "to": "ni_16655291011656"
    },
    {
      "id": "166552910117125",
      "from": "ni_166552910116817",
      "to": "ni_16655291011669"
    },
    {
      "id": "166552910117227",
      "from": "ni_166552910116818",
      "to": "ni_166552910116712"
    },
    {
      "id": "166552910117329",
      "from": "ni_166552910116819",
      "to": "ni_166552910116715"
    }
  ],
  "panning": {},
  "scaling": 1
}
```

thanks for any help ;)